# How do I achieve Python TCP Socket Client/Server with Communications Encrypted?

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, server, cryptography

*Backstory: what I have done*

`{Codes at the bottom}` I've already coded the multithreaded client and server programs using python socket, with the help of the following sites:

> [I. Echo Client and Server](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#echo-client-and-server)
>
> [II. Socket Server with Multiple Clients | Multithreading | Python](https://codezup.com/socket-server-with-multiple-clients-model-multithreading-python/)
>
> [III. Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data](http://%20https://newbedev.com/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data)

### **Regarding Encryption & Decryption**

> **(1)** Exactly at what places in my codes should I encrypt/decrypt my message? **Do
> I encrypt the messages themselves after the user inputs or do I encrypt the byte streams after the input messages have been encoded?**
>
> **(2)** And **how am I supposed to encrypt/decrypt the communication properly and efficiently?** (It'd be nice to see code solutions with explanation, many thanks)

### **My Codes Currently**

*_server.py*

```
import socket
import os
from _thread import *
import struct # Here to convert Python data types into byte streams (in string) and back

# ---- To Avoid Message Boundary Problem on top of TCP protocol ----
def send_msg(sock: socket, msg):  # ---- Use this to send
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock: socket):       # ---- Use this to receive
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock: socket, n: int):
    # Helper function to receive n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data

# ---- Server Communication Setup

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
ThreadCount = 0

try: # create socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print ("Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

try: # bind socket to an address
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print('Waitiing for a Connection..')
s.listen(3)

def threaded_client(conn: socket):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome to the Server'))
    while True:
        # data = conn.recv(2048) # receive message from client
        data = recv_msg(conn)
        reply = 'Server Says: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        # conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        send_msg(conn, str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()

while True:
    Client, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, )) # Calling threaded_client() on a new thread
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))
s.close()
```

*_client.py*

```
import socket
import struct # Here to convert Python data types into byte streams (in string) and back 

# ---- To Avoid Message Boundary Problem on top of TCP protocol ----
def send_msg(sock: socket, msg):  # ---- Use this to send
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock: socket):       # ---- Use this to receive
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock: socket, n: int):
    # Helper function to receive n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data

# ---- Client Communication Setup ----

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print ("Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

print('Waiting for connection')
try:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

Response = s.recv(1024)
while True:
    Input = input('Say Something: ')
    # s.send(str.encode(Input))
    send_msg(s, str.encode(Input))
    # Response = s.recv(1024)
    Response = recv_msg(s)
    print(Response.decode('utf-8'))

s.close()
```

Comment: Just use TLS/SSL, there are plenty of examples on this website and in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to Encrypt the Message itself. I would use RSA to Encrypt the Messages.
If you plan on using multiple Servers, you can open a second Port and if someone connects to it, the Server/Host. Sends the Public Key to the Client.
After that, the Client sends his Public key to the Server.

Now Server and Client switch Ports, and Communicate over there while using the Public key of the other to Encrypt the Messages and decrypt them with their Private key.

You can also Hard-code the Public Keys, if you only have one Server and one Client.

A good Module for RSA Encryption is PyCrytodome.

Here is an Example of to encrypt messages with PyCrytodome.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

def encrypt(pk_receiver, message):
    key = RSA.import_key(pk_receiver)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
    c = cipher.encrypt(message.encode())
    return c

def decrypt(sk, c):
    key = RSA.import_key(sk)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
    m = cipher.decrypt(c)
    return m

def generate_sk(key_length):
    key = RSA.generate(key_length)
    with open('./secret_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(key.export_key(format='PEM'))
    return key


def generate_pk(sk):
    pk = sk.public_key()
    with open('./public_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pk.export_key(format='PEM'))
    return
```

Comment: This approach has multiple vulnerabilities (man in middle attack, key management, ...). When it comes to securing data in transit, usually TLS/SSL/HTTPS is better answer.